I have phpmailer error on woocommere checkout
I'm trying to set up WooCommerce and encountering the error: "There has been a critical error on this website" during checkout. I have disabled all plugins and tested a fresh WordPress installation on a subdomain, but the issue persists.
[25-Sep-2024 11:11:23 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function PHPMailer\PHPMailer\mail() in /home/bontonst/public_html/wp-includes/PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php:881
Stack trace:
#0 /home/bontonst/public_html/wp-includes/PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php(1972): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->mailPassthru()
#1 /home/bontonst/public_html/wp-includes/PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php(1693): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->mailSend()
#2 /home/bontonst/public_html/wp-includes/PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php(1525): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->postSend()
#3 /home/bontonst/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php(546): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->send()
#4 /home/bontonst/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/emails/class-wc-email.php(741): wp_mail()
#5 /home/bontonst/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/emails/class-wc-email-new-order.php(112): WC_Email->send()
#6 /home/bontonst/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(324): WC_Email_New_Order->trigger()
#7 /home/bontonst/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(348): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#8 /home/bontonst/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(565): WP_Hook->do_action()
#9 /home/bontonst/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-emails.php(172): do_action_ref_array()
#10 /home/bontonst/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(324): WC_Emails::send_transactional_email()
#11 /home/bontonst/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(348): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#12 /home/bontonst/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action()
#13 /home/bontonst/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-order.php(420): do_action()
#14 /home/bontonst/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-order.php(253): WC_Order->status_transition()
#15 /home/bontonst/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-order.php(365): WC_Order->save()
#16 /home/bontonst/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/gateways/bacs/class-wc-gateway-bacs.php(390): WC_Order->update_status()
#17 /home/bontonst/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/src/StoreApi/Legacy.php(54): WC_Gateway_BACS->process_payment()
#18 /home/bontonst/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(324): Automattic\WooCommerce\StoreApi\Legacy->process_legacy_payment()
#19 /home/bontonst/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(348): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#20 /home/bontonst/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(565): WP_Hook->do_action()
#21 /home/bontonst/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/src/StoreApi/Utilities/CheckoutTrait.php(83): do_action_ref_array()
#22 /home/bontonst/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/src/StoreApi/Routes/V1/Checkout.php(349): Automattic\WooCommerce\StoreApi\Routes\V1\Checkout->process_payment()
#23 /home/bontonst/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/src/StoreApi/Routes/V1/AbstractRoute.php(119): Automattic\WooCommerce\StoreApi\Routes\V1\Checkout->get_route_post_response()
#24 /home/bontonst/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/src/StoreApi/Routes/V1/Checkout.php(138): Automattic\WooCommerce\StoreApi\Routes\V1\AbstractRoute->get_response_by_request_method()
#25 /home/bontonst/public_html/wp-includes/rest-api/class-wp-rest-server.php(1230): Automattic\WooCommerce\StoreApi\Routes\V1\Checkout->get_response()
#26 /home/bontonst/public_html/wp-includes/rest-api/class-wp-rest-server.php(1063): WP_REST_Server->respond_to_request()
#27 /home/bontonst/public_html/wp-includes/rest-api/class-wp-rest-server.php(439): WP_REST_Server->dispatch()
#28 /home/bontonst/public_html/wp-includes/rest-api.php(420): WP_REST_Server->serve_request()
#29 /home/bontonst/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(324): rest_api_loaded()
#30 /home/bontonst/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(348): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#31 /home/bontonst/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(565): WP_Hook->do_action()
#32 /home/bontonst/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php(418): do_action_ref_array()
#33 /home/bontonst/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php(813): WP->parse_request()
#34 /home/bontonst/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php(1336): WP->main()
#35 /home/bontonst/public_html/wp-blog-header.php(16): wp()
#36 /home/bontonst/public_html/index.php(17): require('/home/bontonst/...')
#37 {main}
  thrown in /home/bontonst/public_html/wp-includes/PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php on line 881


As far as I know, PHPMailer\PHPMailer\mail is from a really old PHPMailer version. It appears the WooCommerce version you are using expects such an outdated version of the library, but your system is using a more current one.

If you haven't edited any of these files manually, this should be a bug in Wordpress. Please report it to them, as you should not fix it on your own anyways

Also: as far as I see, mailPassthru calls the built-in mail method of PHP. Did you check whether that method might be disabled through PHP's disabled_functions setting?

Please share what version of WordPress and what version of WooCommerce you are using

WooCommerce version: 9.3.3
Wordpress version: 6.6.2

I just installed WP Mail SMTP and it works.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
